# Django haystack, whoosh search, boost

Tags: django, search, django-haystack

I have set up django with haystack.
Here is my main model:

```
class Apple(models.Model):
    pname = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    qname = models.CharField(max_length=127)
```

I want to search in apples which have "Test Query" in pname or qname fileds. but I want to show objects that have "Test Query" in their pname field higher than objects that have it in their qname fields.

and here is my search_indexes:

```
class AppIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    pname = CharField(model_attr='pname', boost=1.2)
    qname = CharField(model_attr='qname')
```

here is apple_text.txt file:

```
{{ object.pname }}
{{ object.qname }}
```

I searched a lot, and I think with boost=1.2 it should work but it did not work and there is no difference between objects that have "Test Query" in their pname and qname fields.

Comment: Did you work out how to do this?

Comment: We used elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's changed since the question was asked but I believe you want field_boost=1.2